# Segmentation Fault when i do assign a value in an array in a funtion

Tags: c, arrays, segmentation-fault, malloc

I did debug the program, and the segmentation fault does appear in when I do a[k] = a[h].
The array a is a dinamic array, so I can't understand where is the problem...
Can you help me?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

void Invert(char* a, int k, int h) {
    if(k < h) {
        char app;
        app = a[k];
        a[k] = a[h]; //here is the error
        a[h] = app;
        Invert(a,k+1,h-1);
        }
}

void CallInvert(char* a, char k) {
    int n = strlen(a);
    Invert(a, k, n-1);
}


int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    char *a; int k,i;
    a = malloc(sizeof(char)*sizeof("Hi, how are you?"));
    a = "Hi, how are you?";
    k = 5;
    if(k>=strlen(a)) {
        printf("ERROR");
        return 0;
    }
    printf("Before: \"%s\"\n", a);
    CallInvert(a,k);
    printf("After: \"%s\"\n",a);
    free(a);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: `a = "Hi, how are you?";` --> `strcpy(a, "Hi, how are you?");`

Comment: `sizeof("Hi, how are you?")` This is wrong and not what `sizeof` does.  If you need the length of a string you use `strlen`.  You can also not assign strings the way you do here `a = "Hi, how are you?";`

Comment: but if a do <pre>malloc = strlen("Hi, how are you")*sizeof(char))<code>, it will ignore the position of the final character of a string, '\0'.

Answer (score 2):

In main(), `a = "Hi, how are you?"` is wrong. You are assigning a pointer to a constant string here. Later when you try to write to the constant string it will crash (As iharob pointed out below, writing to a constant string more specifically termed as causing an 'undefined behavior'; which happens to be a segmentation fault in your platform).

Comment: It will not crash, it's undefined behavior and one of the possible things is a segmentation fault.

Comment: if i do 'a[] = "hi, how are you?"'.
Do i make the same error?

Comment: `a[] = "hi, how are you?"` is invalid in C syntax and will not compile. You can use `strcpy(a, "...")`. Please make sure you have sufficient size of `a` allocated including the terminating 0.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use `strcpy` function. Like:

```
a = malloc(sizeof(char)*sizeof("Hi, how are you?"));
    strcpy(a ,"Hi, how are you?");
```

SEGFAULT is cause you can't change value constat literal.

Answer (score 0):

See my changes in the peace of code for memory allocation:

```
    a = (char*)malloc(sizeof(char)* (sizeof("Hi, how are you?") + 1) );
    strcpy(a,"Hi, how are you?");
```

`sizeof("Hi, how are you?")` works correctly, but to store `'\0'` (end of string) you need one more character. And of course `strcpy` or `strncpy` for copying characters to modifiable memory.

Answer (score 0):

I tried executing several times and did not find the problem in the line you have mentioned above, now my code looks like this:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

void Invert(char* a, int k, int h) {
    if (k < h) {
        char app;
        app = a[k];
        a[k] = a[h];
        a[h] = app;
        Invert(a, k + 1, h - 1);
    }
}

void CallInvert(char* a, char k) {
    int n = strlen(a);
    Invert(a, k, n - 1);
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    char *a = NULL; 
    int k;
    a = (char *)malloc(sizeof(char)*strlen("Hi, how are you?") + 1);
    strcpy(a, "Hi, how are you?");
    k = 5;
    if (k >= strlen(a)) {
        printf("ERROR");
        return 0;
    }
    printf("Before: \"%s\"\n", a);
    CallInvert(a, k);
    printf("After: \"%s\"\n", a);
    free(a);
    return 0;
}
```

It seems to work fine and produced the output:

> Before: "Hi, how are you?"
>
> After: "Hi, h?uoy era wo"

Here are some changes that i have made:

1. Used `strlen` to get the length of string, and `strcpy` to copy string, but I see that it has
   already been captured in comment, I am leaving it here for clarity.
2. Typecasted return value of malloc to `char *`, as Visual studio was
   throwing error. This actually depends on what platform you are
   running on.

Comment: I am using codeblocks, so I think it's the same.
Thank you :D

Answer (score 0):

Your problem results from assigning a string literal to your pointer, which overwrites the address returned by `malloc`. This also means that your call to `free` will trigger undefined behavior, such as a segfault, because you're effectively doing this:

```
char *a;
a = "Hi, how are you?";
free (a);
```

You also cannot free the memory to which `malloc` returned a pointer. This means you have a memory leak.

As others have stated, you want to copy the string using `strcpy`:

```
a = malloc (sizeof "Hi, how are you?");
strcpy (a, "Hi, how are you?");
```

Then things should work fine.

Ignore the people who don't know how to use `sizeof` in this context. They likely don't know, until now, that a string literal is considered an array of characters, plus 1 extra character slot for the null terminator, not just a pointer to such an array. You can use `strlen` and add 1 to it if you like, but this fails when you have embedded null characters, unlike the `sizeof` operator:

```
#define HELLO "Hello\0World!"
printf (
    "%zu\n%zu\n",
    sizeof HELLO,
    strlen (HELLO) + 1
);
```

Plus I just don't like calling a function and performing arithmetic when the compiler can do it for me without that overhead.

However, once you assign a string literal to a pointer, you remove any size information, which is probably where the misconception about `sizeof` and string literals comes from. In such a case, using `strlen` is safer. To be fair, I'm not aware of any code that actually embeds null characters in string literals that function as operands to `sizeof` operators.